# Problem Type error and parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 200 OK in jqgrid . please help me out

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Found this error

> Type error in console
> parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 200 OK

Code:

```
$.ajax({
    
    type: "POST",
    url: "PCM/DataToDisplayPCM",
    success: function (dataJson) {
        //var json = JSON.parse(dataJson);
        var json = $.parseJSON(dataJson);

        //debugger;
        $("#table").jqGrid({
            data: json,
            datatype: "JSON",
            height: 'auto',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            colModel: [

                { name: 'ProdPriority', label: 'Priority', index: 'ProdPriority', width: 50 },
                { name: 'ProductCode', label: 'Product Code', index: 'ProductCode', width: 80 },
                { name: 'ProductName', label: 'Product Name', index: 'ProductName', width: 200 },

                { name: 'DIV', label: 'Division', index: 'Division', width: 60 },
                { name: 'Category', label: 'Categary', index: 'Category', width: 150 },

                { name: 'SubCategory', label: 'SubCategary', index: 'SubCategory', width: 150 },
                { name: 'Priority_1', label: 'Priority_1', index: 'Priority_1', width: 80 },
                { name: 'Priority1per', label: 'Priority_1%', index: 'Priority1per', width: 80 },
                { name: 'Priority_2', label: 'Priority_2', index: 'Priority_2', width: 80 },
                { name: 'Priority2per', label: 'Priority_2%', index: 'Priority2per', width: 80 },
                { name: 'Priority_3', label: 'Priority_3', index: 'Priority_3', width: 80 },
                { name: 'Priority3per', label: 'Priority_3%', index: 'Priority3per', width: 80 },
            ],

            pager: "#prowed1",
            sortname: 'P_CODE',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            

        });
        jQuery("#table").jqGrid('navGrid', "#prowed1", { edit: false, add: false, del: false });

     
    }
});
```

This is my jquery code .

Requirement : just data from ajax call and use received data in jqgrid

Controller code returns json data in string

error facing :

> Type error
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jqGrid is not a function

and inside grid :

> parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 200 OK

and I keep only one universal jQuery link in layout

Comment: Please include your code and errors as text and not as an image.

Comment: This means `dataJson` contains HTML, not JSON. Maybe the script that's supposed to return JSON got an error.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: The error shows that the jqGrid is not loaded and there may be other problems. I recommend you to post the whole page or send a link for the problem.

Comment: Break up the steps.
Do not try to one line code...let the compiler do that trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah error got cleared .

mainly i separated loading jqgrid and ajax call
1)loaded jqgrid with col model
2)just removed datatype while loading grid

3)in ajax sucess :used "datatype: local" and "data: mydata"

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "PCM/DataToDisplayPCM",
       success: function (dataJson) {
           pcmjson = JSON.parse(dataJson);
           $("#table").jqGrid().setGridParam({
                datatype: 'local',
                data: pcmjson
           }).trigger('reloadGrid');

       }
   })
```